# Acceder al valor de una propiedad de un objeto a partir de otra propiedad

Tags: javascript

Necesito hacer una función que cuando le pase el parámetro "nombre" me retorne el precio de ese nombre, es decir que si a la función le paso el parámetro 2, yo reciba el valor del precio de ese objeto es decir me debe devolver 3.

```
Var array=[{ nombre:1, Precio:2}, {nombre:2, Precio:3}]
```

Comment: Para poder ayudarte has de mostrar lo que has intentado hacer por tu cuenta. Puedes leer [mcve] como guía. Haz clic en [edit] y agrega los detalles relevantes de lo que has intentado. Saludos

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es interesante cuando haces una pregunta, que intentes mostrar algo de código, así podemos ver donde puedes tener el problema o la duda.

En cualquier caso si quieres crear una función que te devuelva un valor dentro de un objeto en un array, lo más cómodo hoy en día en JavaScript es usar el método Filter().

[Filter JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) / [Video sobre Filter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n3lSI9W_ryg)

Lee esta documentación y no tendrás ninguna duda más de cómo crear esa función. Cualquier duda aquí estamos.

Un Saludo y ánimo!!

pd: ejemplo fácil de entender.

```
const productos = [
  
  {nombre: 'camisa', precio: 5},
  {nombre: 'jersey', precio: 23},
  {nombre: 'bolso', precio: 45},
  {nombre: 'zapatos', precio: 55},
  {nombre: 'cinturon', precio: 15}
  
]

const precioProducto = productos.filter((producto)=>(
  producto.nombre === 'camisa' //primero filtras para seleccionar el producto
)).map((producto)=>(producto.precio)) // recorres el producto y extraes el precio

console.log(precioProducto)
```

Comment: Gracias, soy nuevo en esto, veo que aún sigo con muchas falencias, debo estudiar mucho más, muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta, entendí el código, solo llevo un par de días en este mundo de la programación

Comment: ánimo!!! lo importante es entender lo que quieres hacer, reducirlo a trocitos de problema, y sacar el problema grande. Leer documentación oficial ayuda mucho. Aquí estamos. Un Saludo